# get error when use pp for perl script under Ubuntu

Tags: perl

command:

```
pp -o test -A addlist.txt test1.pl
```

content in addlist.txt:

```
lib_3.pm
lib
```

there are `lib_1.pm` and `lib_2.pm` under folder `lib`
test1.pl call functions defined in `lib_1.pm` and `lib_2.pm` and `lib_3.pm`

after I run the command above, I get error:

```
for packingin/pp: cannot find file or directory lib_3.pm
for packingin/pp: cannot find file or directory lib
```

Although I get the error, the output file from pp can print correct output. Who can tell me why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Maybe try running `pp` through the debugger: `perl -d pp -o test -A addlist.txt test1.pl` and try to locate the problem? Or add an issue at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/rschupp/PAR-Packer)

Comment: Have you put `use lib 'lib';` in your perl script?

Comment: yes, I did use `use lib path_of_lib` in my script

Answer (score 1):

I get help from githut.

The error is because the end of line of addlist.txt is windows. When I save the addlist.txt as Unix/Linux end of line, the error gong.